# why is this linq query return a boolean and not the first result of the select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array with 5 items. How to get one of these 5 items by a linq query?

Code below returns only a boolean true.

```
string[] allWebTemplateSettings =SiteLidmaatschapSettings.Current.ProvisioningSettings;
var webTemplate = allWebTemplateSettings
           .Select(x => x.StartsWith(string.Format("Template:{0}", web.WebTemplate)))
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You are selecting the return value of StartsWith which is of type bool

Answer (score 12):

Use `Where` instead of `Select`:

```
var webTemplate = allWebTemplateSettings.Where(x => x.StartsWith(string.Format("Template:{0}", web.WebTemplate))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you're getting an `IEnumerable` of bools with your `Select`, then you pick the first one if there are any. That's why you're getting a `bool` as your answer.

I think what you actually want is this:

```
string[] allWebTemplateSettings = SiteLidmaatschapSettings.Current.ProvisioningSettings;
var prefix = string.Format("Template:{0}", web.WebTemplate);
var webTemplate = allWebTemplateSettings
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(prefix));
```

I've moved the string formatting operation out of the predicate since it is wasteful to recompute it for each element in your collection (especially if the collection is long).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), which *selects* a new value based on each existing value of a sequence, with [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx), which filters a sequence so it only contains items *where* a condition is met.

The simplest change is to replace your usage of `Select` with `Where`.

```
string[] allWebTemplateSettings = SiteLidmaatschapSettings.Current.ProvisioningSettings;
var webTemplate = allWebTemplateSettings
    .Where(x => x.StartsWith(string.Format("Template:{0}", web.WebTemplate)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The other answers have rolled this usage of `Where` into `FirstOrDefault` without explaining your underlying confusion.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `StartsWith` returns a `bool` and you're saying `Select` that `bool` based on whether it starts with that value or not. So actually, you're not even filtering on that value at all because **you're not using a filter expression**.

Actually, you only need `FirstOrDefault` as the list is already a `List<string>`

```
string[] allWebTemplateSettings = SiteLidmaatschapSettings.Current.ProvisioningSettings;
 var webTemplate = allWebTemplateSettings
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(string.Format("Template:{0}", web.WebTemplate)));
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would you select an identical item?

Comment: Technically he doesn't *need* a `Select`

Comment: Yep you're both right, he doesn't need the `Select` as it's a collection of strings anyway.